# How can I use R rowsum or other tools to change the resolution of the data? (from mm / frame of video to mm / minute)

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, time-series, data-cleaning

I'm working in an undergraduate zebrafish lab trying to quantify behavior as a function of locomotion. We use Noldus Ethovision to calculate positions, updated at 30 frames per second for 25 minutes.

The differencing algorithm it employs is pretty spotty, but our primary issue is the sheer volume of data. 45,000 cells for a single fish's locomotion data, across hundreds of fish, is not possible for manual cleaning. The data output gives a column of time as decimal fractions, with ~ 30 cells per second, e.g.

the data is a bit noisy
[image]

I tried using which() to transform my time in frames data into categorical time (minute class) data, so that I may use rowsums to calculate cumulative mm swum per minute.
[image: time column]
[image: making a categorical minute column to perform rowsums]
[image: transforming every number less than or equal to 60 to 1]
[image: error when keep trying to transform]

I've run into this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: notation `a < x <= b` does not do what you want in R. Use `a < x & x <= b`

Comment: And please, do not share your data as images, please use code block and if possible the output of `dput(df)` or `dput(head(df, 50))` for a sample.